# Getting sum of datagridview row error

Tags: c#, datagridview

i'm here because I'm getting an error while clicking at the button.
The error is, that when I press the button, he automatically sums rows values to add as text in labels, but I'm getting this error: "invalidcastexception was unhandled" and stop debugging at `somasiva += Convert.ToSingle(Vendas.dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[3]);`

```
private void btnConfirmar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string Produto = cbproduto.SelectedItem.ToString();
        int Quantidade = Convert.ToInt32(txtquantidade.Text);
        float Preco = Convert.ToSingle(txtpreco.Text);
        float IVA = Convert.ToSingle(txtiva.Text);
        float Total = (Convert.ToSingle(Preco) * Convert.ToInt32(Quantidade)) + (Convert.ToSingle(txtiva.Text) * Convert.ToInt32(Quantidade));

        object[] row = new object[] { Produto, Quantidade, Preco, IVA, Total };

        Vendas.dataGridView1.Rows.Add(row);
        Vendas.dataGridView1.Update();
        float somasiva = 0, somaiva = 0, somaciva = 0;
        int i;
        for (i = 0; i < Vendas.dataGridView1.Rows.Count; ++i)
        {
            somasiva += Convert.ToSingle(Vendas.dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[3]);
            somaiva += Convert.ToSingle(Vendas.dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[4]);
            somaciva += Convert.ToSingle(Vendas.dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[5]);
        }
        Vendas.lblsiva.Text = somasiva.ToString() + " €";
        Vendas.lbliva.Text = somaiva.ToString() + " €";
        Vendas.lblciva.Text = somaciva.ToString() + " €";
        Vendas.lblciva.Update();
        Vendas.lblsiva.Update();
        Vendas.lbliva.Update();
        this.Close();
    }
```

Can you tell me what I did wrong? Because that code is basically the same as I saw in a video and at some questions here... And I want to take for somasiva = Preco ; somaiva = IVA ; somaciva = Total;...

Comment: Does the `Vendas.dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[3]` data contains any of the currency symbols?

Comment: http://i.imgur.com/pOWawPf.png I got it like this...